# Find the maximum product sales with planning schedules

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a dynamic programming problem and actually, I'm not quite sure whether it is dynamic programming since moving average M is based on previous M. No need to consider the efficiency. The problem requires selling a product over T time periods and maximizing the total actual sale amount. The total number of products is N and I plan to sell some products over different periods n0,n1,⋯,nT−1 and ∑ni=N.

In conclusion, this question wants to find the most optimal schedule for n0,n1,⋯,nT−1 such that ∑ni=N, which maximizes the ∑Si.

And the actual sale amount Si are based on current moving average M and current ni.
Assume that α=0.001 and π=0.5

1. Initialize M=0. Then for i=0,1,…,T−1
2. Compute new Mi=⌈0.5∗(Mi+ni)⌉
3. At time i we sell Si = ⌈(1−α*M^πi)*ni⌉ products 

   Continue this process until the last time period. For example, assume we already know ni for all periods, the trading will be below

```
    M = 0
    T = 4
    N = 10000
    alpha = 1e-3
    pi = 0.5
    S = np.zeros(T,dtype='i')
    n  = np.array([5000,1000,2000,2000])
    print(n)
    total = 0
    for i in range(T):
        M = math.ceil(0.5*(M + n[i]))
        S[i] = math.ceil((1 - alpha*M**pi)*n[i])
        total += S[i]
        print('at time %d, M = %d and we sell %d products' %(i,M,S[i]))
    print('total sold =', total)
```

My idea is to keep track of the state based on t time period, n products left, and m moving average as index and store the actual sale in a high dimension matrix. I think the upper bound for moving average is just [0,n] I'm still confusing how to program it. Could someone provide ideas about how to fix some problems in my programming? Thank you very much.
The below is some of my crude codes but the output is a little strange.

```
def DPtry(N,T,alpha,pi,S):
    schedule = np.zeros(T)
    M = 0
    
    for n in range(0,N+1):
        for m in range(0,n+1):
            S[T-1,n,m] = math.ceil((1 - alpha*m**pi)*n)
    
    for k in range(1,T):
        t = T - k - 1
        print("t = ",t)
        for n in range(0,N+1):
            for m in range(0,n+1):
                best = -1
                
                for plan in range(0,n+1):
                    salenow = math.ceil((1 - alpha*m**pi)*plan)
                    M = math.ceil(0.5*(m + plan))
                    salelater = S[t+1,n-plan,M]
                    candidate = salenow + salelater
                    if candidate > best:
                        best = candidate
                S[t,n,m] = best
                
    print(S[0,N,0])
```

```
N = 100
T = 5
pi = .5
alpha = 1e-3

S = np.zeros((T,N+1,N+1))
DPtry(N,T,alpha,pi,S)
```

Comment: is this supposed to be ``for m in range(0,n+1):`` and not capital ``N+1``?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - if you are struggling with a specific problem, please point it out and make your question specific to it. If you are more looking for a code review, SO is not the right place and you should ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (as a general note though, using single letter variables, especially when mixing capitals and lower case names, is setting yourself up for failure and certainly not Pythonic)